# Display div when selected option contains specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery

If user choose any option from list which contains `C-D` (in value or label it doesn't matter in this case) I would like to show next option list.
I tried with contains() Selector but somewhere there is a mistake.

My HTML structure:

```js
<script>
$(function () {
  $("#choose-material").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val:contains('C-D')) {
        $("#choose-size").show();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

```css
#choose-size {display: none;)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="material-type" id="choose-material">
 <option value="C-D">C-D</option>
 <option value="VV_C-D">VV_C-D</option>
 <option value="VV_C-B">VV_C-B</option>
 <option value="B_C-D">B_C-D</option>
 <option value="GL_WW">GL_WW</option>
</select>

<select name="material-size" id="choose-size">
 <option value="Small">Small</option>
 <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
 <option value="Big">Big</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:contains()` selector is intended for use in jQuery objects. To check if the `val` string contains `C-D` you can instead use `indexOf()`.

Also note that you can simplify the logic by using `toggle()` and providing a boolean result as an argument which will in turn show or hide the given element. Finally, note that your CSS had a trailing `)` instead of `}`.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#choose-material").change(function() {
    $("#choose-size").toggle($(this).val().indexOf('C-D') != -1);
  }).change();
});
```

```css
#choose-size {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="material-type" id="choose-material">
  <option value="C-D">C-D</option>
  <option value="VV_C-D">VV_C-D</option>
  <option value="VV_C-B">VV_C-B</option>
  <option value="B_C-D">B_C-D</option>
  <option value="GL_WW">GL_WW</option>
</select>

<select name="material-size" id="choose-size">
  <option value="Small">Small</option>
  <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
  <option value="Big">Big</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you very much, your solution works in the best way.

Comment: I just found another issue, when I change option where there is no C-D the second select list is hiding but the option is still choosed. How could I reset it to default (empty) option?

Comment: You don't appear to have an empty option in the HTML you showed, but if you did you can select it with `$("#choose-size").val('');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Note that for more browser compatibility you can use [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) like this `$(this).val().indexOf('C-D') !== -1`

Code:

```js
$('#choose-material').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val().includes('C-D')) {
      $("#choose-size").show();
  }
});
```

```css
#choose-size {display: none;)
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="material-type" id="choose-material">
 <option value="C-D">C-D</option>
 <option value="VV_C-D">VV_C-D</option>
 <option value="VV_C-B">VV_C-B</option>
 <option value="B_C-D">B_C-D</option>
 <option value="GL_WW">GL_WW</option>
</select>

<select name="material-size" id="choose-size">
 <option value="Small">Small</option>
 <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
 <option value="Big">Big</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Note that this is completely unsupported in IE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you for the comment.. Added more browser compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$(function () {
 $("#choose-material").change(function() {
 var val = $(this).val();
 if(val.indexOf("C-D")>=0) {
    $("#choose-size").show();
  }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the selected value contains the `C-D` substring via a regex of shape `/C-D/g`, as such:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#choose-material").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val.match(/C\-D/g)) {
        $("#choose-size").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#choose-size {display: none;)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="material-type" id="choose-material">
 <option value="C-D">C-D</option>
 <option value="VV_C-D">VV_C-D</option>
 <option value="VV_C-B">VV_C-B</option>
 <option value="B_C-D">B_C-D</option>
 <option value="GL_WW">GL_WW</option>
</select>

<select name="material-size" id="choose-size">
 <option value="Small">Small</option>
 <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
 <option value="Big">Big</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

.contains() and .includes() are both experimental, re: non-standard. I would not recommend their use in production systems. I'd stick with .indexOf() for now.

It's easy with the indexOf method, you can see a tutorial of indexOf and substring here: http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/javascript-shell-scripting/strings-tutorial.php

```css
#choose-size {display: none;)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
  $("#choose-material").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val.indexOf('C-D') !== -1) {
        $("#choose-size").show();
    } else {
        $("#choose-size").hide();
    }
  });
});
</script>

<select name="material-type" id="choose-material">
 <option value="C-D">C-D</option>
 <option value="VV_C-D">VV_C-D</option>
 <option value="VV_C-B">VV_C-B</option>
 <option value="B_C-D">B_C-D</option>
 <option value="GL_WW">GL_WW</option>
</select>

<select name="material-size" id="choose-size">
 <option value="Small">Small</option>
 <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
 <option value="Big">Big</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues with your code:

1. You are missing the `$("#choose-size").hide();` when the value do not contain `C-D`
2. You need to use `indexOf()` or `includes()` to check if the value contains `C-D`. Preference is to use `indexOf()` as `includes()` do not work in IE browser.

```js
$(function () {
  $("#choose-material").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val.indexOf('C-D') !== -1) {
        $("#choose-size").show();
    } else {
       $("#choose-size").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#choose-size {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="material-type" id="choose-material">
 <option value="C-D">C-D</option>
 <option value="VV_C-D">VV_C-D</option>
 <option value="VV_C-B">VV_C-B</option>
 <option value="B_C-D">B_C-D</option>
 <option value="GL_WW">GL_WW</option>
</select>

<select name="material-size" id="choose-size">
 <option value="Small">Small</option>
 <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
 <option value="Big">Big</option>
</select>
```